# Disabling or removing alarm from '98 Lexus ES300?

Tags: toyota, maintenance, camry, lexus, alarm

I have a '98 Lexus ES300, and if I try to open any door when the car is locked, the alarm will be activated. What I do is when the alarm starts blaring is that I get in the car and turn the ignition, which disables the alarm. To avoid this I just leave one door unlocked, but that obviously has security issues.

Is there a way to permanently disable this alarm? I don't have the key with the alarm buttons. I'm 99% sure that it's the factory alarm.

I've had this issue for several years now. A few years ago I was able to disable the alarm by opening the trunk, but that doesn't work anymore.

I would like to permanently disable/remove the alarm. If that's not possible, then another option is to be able to disable the alarm by opening the trunk.

Comment: Unlock the car before opening the door... But why don't the locks work properly?

Answer (score -2):

Try finding the fuse that leads to the alarm and yank it out... That should disable it.

Comment: Many alarm systems have batteries built in, so that if you cut the main battery cables on the vehicle the alarm will still sound.